# I keep getting these errors when running "sudo apt-get update" in my Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I've been trying every method but they just cant fix those.

[image: Screenshot of update error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). Please in the future, do not submit screenshots of text. It's difficult to read and impossible to work with. Instead give the command and copy/paste the output. You can [format](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) your post to preserve line breaks and formatting

Comment: Either wait for the mirror to resume useful function, or change to a more reliable mirror. Your choice. To change mirrors, open your Desktop Search. Look for the "Software & Updates" control panel. Find the "Ubuntu Software" Tab. Look for the "Download from" line. Select a different server.